# any advice on how I can do the loop to remove the nth element?

Tags: java, sorting

Write a method, downsize, that will remove every nth element from a LinkedList of employee names.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class LinkedListDemo
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      LinkedList<String> staff = new LinkedList<String>();
      staff.add("John");
      staff.add("Bob");
      staff.add("Richard");
      staff.add("Alice");
      staff.add("Jane");
      staff.add("Carlos");
      staff.add("Jose");
      staff.add("Maria");

      downsize(staff, 3);
      System.out.println(staff);
      System.out.println("Expected: [John, Bob, Alice, Jane, Jose, Maria]");

   }

   public static void downsize(LinkedList<String> employeeNames, int n)
   {
      ListIterator<String> iter = employeeNames.listIterator();

      for(int i=n; i<employeeNames.size(); i++)
      {
         iter.next();
      }

      iter.remove();


   }

}
```

I'm having some troubles to find a perfect loop that can remove any nth element in my ListIterator. thank you!

Comment: Well, you'll need a counter to track the *n*, right? And every time that counter hits the number, you remove that element, and continue iterating from that point.

Comment: okay cool. is there any other way i can do this but without using the ListIterator or do i need it always?

Answer (score 3):

This will remove every n-th element from the employeeNames LinkedList:

```
for(int i=0; i<employeeNames.size(); i++)
  {
     iter.next();
     if (i % n == 0) iter.remove();
  }
```

Comment: You should not provide full answers to homework questions - only hints and guidelines

Comment: thanks for the quick feedback. i have one more question about the code you just wrote. can it be done in a different way without using the ListIterator or it is the only way?

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize it was a homework question (did not pay attention to the tags).  @jesusSandoval: You don't have to instantiate the iterator, but since this is a LinkedList this is the most efficient way to implement this.  You should think how to alternatively implement this using an ArrayList.

Comment: On second thaught it might be ok in this specific case, since the OP already did try already, and just needed a help where and how to remove() the elements from iterator...

Comment: Let me understand what you just said. so it is more efficient to implement the linkedList by using the Iterator. is it correct?

Comment: Max the for loop was correct. but the if statement was not right it was like this:     if((i+1)%n==0) iter.remove()

Comment: @jesusSandoval: An iterator is the best way to move through a LinkedList.  You could also simply write for (int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++) { if (i % n == 0) employees.remove(i); }, but this would be very inneficient. Do you see why?

Comment: i think it was like this since we start at index 0

Answer (score 0):

Never ever modify a list that you are currently iterating over. That way madness lies.

```
public static List<String> downsize(List<String> employeeNames, int n) {
    Set<String> employeesToRemove = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int index = n; index < employeeNames.size(); index += n) {
        employeesToRemove.add(employeeNames.get(index);
    }
    employeeNames.removeAll(employeesToRemove);
}
```

If, however, you absolutely must iterate over the array, here is that madness also.

```
public static List<String> downsize(List<String> employeeNames, int n) {
    for (int index = employeeNames.size() -  (n -(employeeNames.size()  % n))  ; index >= 0; index -= n) {
        employeeNames.remove(index);
    }
    return employeeNames;
}
```

Comment: This is a homework, so the implementation speed probably doesn't matter.  But I think it is still important for the student to understand that your solution is _not_ appropriate. 1) There is no problem in using Iterator.remove(). That's what it exists for. 2) Your solution, apart from being more complex and instatiating a utility Set, also runs in O(N^2) time for a LinkedList. The same is true of your second solution.  Any get(), remove() or add() operation on a LinkedList runs in O(N) time...